# Checking scratched CD integrity

Tags: sound, cd

I've an old music CD and it's all scratched, is there anyway that i could check if there is any unreadable part on it?
Something like `fsck` for CDs/DVDs?

Comment: A passed read check doesn't tell you if the data you got is valid or corrupted (e.g., you can have an audio CD that reads fine but yet shows noise/artifacts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tools you can use to recover data on the CD (well, not **all** data, anyway).

The tools I think of are `ddrescue` (or `GNU gddrescue`):

```
ddrescue - copy data from one file or block device to another
gddrescue - the GNU data recovery tool
```

and `dares`:

```
dares - rescue files from damaged CDs and DVDs (ncurses-interface)
dares-qt - rescue files from damaged CDs and DVDs (Qt-interface)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Rubyripper](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Rubyripper). Do a rip of the CD in question. When that's complete you'll get a .log file which will report on how the rip went.

From the [Hydrogenaudio FAQ, Correction mechanism section](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Rubyripper#Correction_mechanism):

> it will repair any files so that it's
>   impossible to successfully blind-test
>   with the original via an ABX test for
>   example. The log file will optionally
>   report any position that needed more
>   than 3 trials, so you can check the
>   position yourself.

That's the best I can think of.